# FB Like button unlikes itself

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Recently facebook rolled out some changes which have apparently broken like button functionality on on pages I'm working on, particularly for urls that point to a photo (photoset) on facebook, e.g. a facebook button like

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=ID&set=SET" ....></fb:like>
```

The button renders, however when I click 'like' it immediately 'unlikes' itself afterwards.  *Non-facebook URLs work fine with the like button, **only** URLs that point to photos/content on facebook cause the like button to immediately unlike itself after it's clicked.  The buttons are generated via the JSSDK as iframes.  Is there a solution to this problem?  We're not using og metadata.

Comment: Have you included the SDK twice or something that would have a similar effect? Because it sounds like your 'like' event is firing twice and so immediately liking and then unliking the link.

Comment: Nope.  It *only* occurs with URLs that point to photos/content on facebook.  Other URLs are fine.  I should update that to say only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always encountered issues with using Facebook's developer tools with resources on its own domain and, for that reason, always recommended "proxying". In other words, you would create a unique resource on your web server to represent the Facebook photo, this resource would garner likes and shares, but when a user visited the page, they would be redirected to the *real* photo.

For example:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.example.com/fakeresources/photo.php?fbid=ID&set=SET" ....></fb:like>
```

When you load `http://www.example.com/fakeresources/photo.php?fbid=ID&set=SET`:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<script>top.location.href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=ID&set=SET";</script>
```

Unfortunately, for the og:image tag, you will also need to create a proxy, because the Facebook scraper will often not fetch from its own servers.

I've even encountered times when Facebook will not fetch from a URL because the URL has a query parameter which looks like a URL which is on its own servers, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/fakeresources?url=facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=ID&set=SET
(query parameter not url-encoded for readability)
```

For which, encoding the URL with [rot-13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook like buttons strips all the get parameters of urls, so although you have this

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=ID&set=SET" ....></fb:like>
```

The url retrieved by facebook is this

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php" ....></fb:like>
```

**EDIT**

As you may have not noticed on the 10th of july one of the break changes is the url of the social plugins

> Social plugins will require an absolute URL in the 'href' parameter 
>   Social plugins, such as the Like Box and Like Button, will require an
>   absolute URL in the 'href' parameter.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#q4_2013